# Openlayer 4 get polygon coordinates after select feature

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I want get coordinates after select feature using interaction.Select.

Fragment of my code:

```
  var selectf = new ol.interaction.Select({
    layers: [vectorLayer],
     }); 
   map.addInteraction(selectf); 


  selectf.on('select', function(evt) {

//here I want read coordinates of selected feature
});
```

How I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

On 'Select' event, you can use the following approach to get the co-ordinate from the vector feature.

```
select.on('select', function(event) {
console.log(event.selected[0].getGeometry().getCoordinates());

  });
```

Comment: Thank Bruce, it's working. But why don't working with geometry Circle?

Answer (score 1):

@BruceWayne's answer is correct for all standard geometries obtained from sources such as geojson (and the question did specify polygon) but if you are using the non-standard circle geometry specific to OpenLayers a special case will be needed:

```
select.on('select', function(event) {
  var geom = event.selected[0].getGeometry();
  if (geom.getType() == 'Circle') {
    console.log(geom.getCenter());
    console.log(geom.getRadius());
  } else {
    console.log(geom.getCoordinates());
  }
});
```